# Different numbers coming from Cloudflare, Smartlook, and Vercel analytics

Tags: analytics, cloudflare, vercel, cisco

Over the last four months, I have used Smartlook (by Cisco) for analytics and Cloudflare for security. I started using Vercel analytics yesterday. I have only added Vercel analytics to my web app; it has not been deployed to mobile yet.

- Cloudflare told me I had 128 unique visitors yesterday.
- Vercel told me I had 22 unique visitors yesterday (web only.)
- Smartlook told me I had 2 unique visitors on the web and 6 unique visitors on mobile.

What might be causing this discrepancy? These are all wildly different numbers, and they will determine how many precautions I take when rolling out new features.

Up until today, I have been primarily trusting Smartlook and being rather risky in my deployment practices (no need to be super cautious when you have 8 visitors a day).

Comment: What about analyzing your own logs and see where the requests come from? Counting to 8, 22, or 128 isn't that hard.

Comment: I have pretty detailed logging on my API, I have about 2k requests made to my api a day and its hard to tell which of those are coming from real humans. 

Currently no logging on any of my clients. 

I'm trusting that one of these services will be the best at determining which visitors are real humans.

Comment: The "hard to tell" part is of course what these services use as selling points - however, if their numbers differ so wildly, at least 2 of them are doing it wrong. The question is: which ones? If you just have standard web server logging, you can at least look at IP addresses and user-agent strings; if you're also logging access tokens or cookies for your API you might get a more precise view. Of course, giving advice is cheap, doing it is real work - you will most likely either need to do it yourself or pay someone to do it for you.